# A bash script for multiple wget commands

Tags: bash, wget

I have mutliple (over 100) similar to this:

```
wget -q -nH --cut-dirs=5 -r -l0 -c -N -np -R 'index*' -erobots=off --retr-symlinks http://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/FTP/swift/data/obs/2009_02//00031327004/auxil/
wget -q -nH --cut-dirs=5 -r -l0 -c -N -np -R 'index*' -erobots=off --retr-symlinks http://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/FTP/swift/data/obs/2009_01//00031327001/uvot/
wget -q -nH --cut-dirs=5 -r -l0 -c -N -np -R 'index*' -erobots=off --retr-symlinks http://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/FTP/swift/data/obs/2010_12//00031856009/uvot/
wget -q -nH --cut-dirs=5 -r -l0 -c -N -np -R 'index*' -erobots=off --retr-symlinks http://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/FTP/swift/data/obs/2008_01//00031043003/uvot/
wget -q -nH --cut-dirs=5 -r -l0 -c -N -np -R 'index*' -erobots=off --retr-symlinks http://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/FTP/swift/data/obs/2012_01//00032237004/uvot/
```

I have been told that this can be completed very quickly and easy with a bash script, could someone give me an example if possible for multiple wget commands? What do I need to include within the script? Apologies for my n00b questions, but...I am one!

Comment: How similar?  What's different between each call?  Just the URL?

Comment: I'll update the answer with a few lines.

Comment: Do you have all these URLs in a text file?

Comment: Yeh, all in a normal .txt file

Comment: `bash your-file-here.txt`, if all you want is to run it as a script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your noob question is about speeding up the process time,

you can spawn multiple process's in background `&` and `wait` for them

```
wget firsturl &
wget secondurl &
...
wait
```

Comment: I'd really prefer a bash script.

Comment: its a bash script, just replace firsturl with what ever you are using

Comment: And this can be placed in a text file to be run as a script?

Comment: yes, just replace ... with all your urls and end each line with `&`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your URL list looks like this:

```
http://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/FTP/swift/data/obs/2009_02//00031327004/auxil/
http://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/FTP/swift/data/obs/2009_01//00031327001/uvot/
http://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/FTP/swift/data/obs/2010_12//00031856009/uvot/
http://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/FTP/swift/data/obs/2008_01//00031043003/uvot/
http://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/FTP/swift/data/obs/2012_01//00032237004/uvot/
```

Just `read` your URLs from the text file using a `while` loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read url; do
    wget -q -nH --cut-dirs=5 -r -l0 -c -N -np -R 'index*' -erobots=off --retr-symlinks "$url"
done < urls.txt
```